# How count of characters getting stored in char array. Basically wanted to the working of increment operator on the array

Tags: java, arrays, character, repeat

```
public static void getCharCountArray(String str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        count[str.charAt(i)]++;
    }
}
```

How is count array getting the count of the character. Working of the increment operator?

Comment: `count[str.charAt(i)] = count[str.charAt(i)] + 1;`

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting in the future. Stack Overflow is designed to be a repository of high quality questions - well-formatted code makes for a *much* clearer than question than a single line with lots of code in.

Comment: Or `count[str.charAt(i)] += 1;`

Comment: could you put the line to construct the count array in your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is an indexed array of integers.
Each index of this array is a char.

The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

In your loop, `str.charAt(i)` return the char of your String str for the current iteration.

You get the previous count for the current char of your String with the expression :

`count[str.charAt(i)]`

and you increment this value with the `++` operator.

we could rewrite your code like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
    int previousCharCount = count[currentChar];
    int currentCharCount = previousCharCount + 1;
    count[currentChar] = currentCharCount;
}
```

Your line : `count[str.charAt(i)]++;` does the same things, but in a simpler and more readable way.

The `++` operator, doesn't operate an increment on the array (non sense) but operates an increment on the integer value at the position `char`.

Comment: Thanks, you explained it very well!

Comment: you're welcome ! but, could you put the line to construct the count array in your code please